# Incorrectly overwriting JSON file

Tags: json, python-3.x

So i have this small json database with list of entries, i tried making a python program that adds new items to the entries list and then overwrites the contents, the thing is, it fills the first line with a bunch of spaces, making JSON file unreadable for python.

```
{"entries":[ 

  ]
}
```

```py
import  json
f=open('test.json',"r+")
data=json.load(f)
def addme(x):
    data["entries"].append({x:{
    "added":True
    }})
addme("jason")
f.truncate(0)
json.dump(data,f, indent=1)
f.close()
```

I expected it to look something like

```
{
 "entries": [
  {
   "jason": {
    "added": true
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

instead i got

```
                    { 
 "entries": [
  {
   "jason": {
    "added": true
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

i tried removing indent parameter but that didn't work.
another interesting thing is that i cant copy paste contents of the file with spaces and spaces themselves.

Comment: @Anshu incorrectly edited the original post and removed the spaces before `{` so the difference between expected and actual was no longer apparent.

Comment: @faradee. sorry guys for do such mistake  .... now you question are same as you aspect. cc trenton_m

Answer (score 0):

Tried opening test.json in "r" mode, loading all data onto variable, closing the file and opening it again in "w+" mode seems to work for me.